# How to store dictionary and list in python config file?

Tags: python, config

I'm using config.ini file to store all my configurations.

I need to store a dictionary and a list in the config file and parse it in my main.py file using configparser. Can anyone please tell me how do I go about doing that?

config.ini:

```
[DEFAULT] 
ADMIN = xyz 
SOMEDICT = {'v1': 'k1', 'v2': 'k2'}
SOMELIST = [v1, v2]
```

main.py:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser() 
config.read('config.ini') 
secret_key = config['DEFAULT']['ADMIN']
```

If there is no way to do this, is config in json format a good option?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the .ini question, but yes, JSON is a good option.

Comment: how would you do this in json, could you please help?

Comment: The other option is to use JSON-compatible values in your ini-file and parse the values with `json.loads`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ConfigParser will only ever give you those elements as strings, which you would then need to parse.

As an alternative, YAML is a good choice for configuration files, since it is easily human readable. Your file could look like this:

```
DEFAULT:
    ADMIN: xyz
    SOMEDICT:
        v1: k1
        v2: k2
    SOMELIST:
        - v1
        - v2
```

and the Python code would be:

```
import yaml
with open('config.yml') as c:
    config = yaml.load(c)
config['DEFAULT']['SOMEDICT']
```

Comment: this really helps. apologies for dumb qs but could you tell me if there is an easy way to get it in the python file in dictionary format? i mean i need list to be list and dict to be dict while getting settings from config file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. The above code gives you list and dict format.

Comment: this is what i get when i print(config['DEFAULT']['SOMEDICT']) -> v1:k1 v2:k2 ... what i need is {'v1': 'k1', 'v2': 'k2'}

Comment: When you use the code that I have given above, the result of `print(config['DEFAULT']['SOMEDICT'])` is `{'v1': 'k1', 'v2': 'k2'}`.

Comment: But that's irrelevant anyway; if all you wanted to do was print it, then your original code which gives the result as a string would work fine.

Comment: i printed it just as an example although i do have more to do with it. i will check what is causing the formatting issue while printing from YML file. thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use `json`:

```
json.loads('[1, 2]') #=> [1, 2]
json.dumps([1, 2]) #=> '[1, 2]'
json.loads('{"v1": "k1", "v2": "k2"}') #=> {'v1': 'k1', 'v2': 'k2'}
json.dumps({'v1': 'k1', 'v2': 'k2'}) #=> '{"v1": "k1", "v2": "k2"}'
```

You will need to do `dumps` before saving and `loads` after reading for those fields you use JSON for.

Better solution would be to use JSON for the entire configuration file:

```
{
  "DEFAULT": {
    "ADMIN": "xyz",
    "SOMEDICT": {
      "v1": "k1",
      "v2": "k2"
    },
    "SOMELIST": [
      "v1",
      "v2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
conf = json.load(open('conf.json'))
json.dump(conf, open('conf.json', 'w'))
```

Answer (score 3):

A JSON file with this data could look like this:

```
{
  "DEFAULT": {
    "ADMIN": "xyz",
    "SOMEDICT": {
      "v1": "k1",
      "v2": "k2"
    },
    "SOMELIST": [
      "v1",
      "v2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then in python:

```
import json

with open('config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is possible to store and read Dict or List data from an ini file**

after reading the value you just have to use the built in **eval( )** function,
by default the variable will be of type string eval will check and convert it to the dictionary data type.

***You can try the following code***

```
dict_data = configur.get("DEFAULT", "SOMEDICT")
dict_data = eval(dict_data)

print(dict_data['v1'])
```