# How can I read in lists within a list using ConfigParser() in Python?

Tags: python, list, config, configparser

I have seen a lot of answers on how to read in a list using ConfigParser in Python:

- [Lists in ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser)
- [Getting a list from a config file with ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759016/getting-a-list-from-a-config-file-with-configparser)
- [How to store dictionary and list in python config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948411/how-to-store-dictionary-and-list-in-python-config-file)
- [Get a list from config.ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769428/get-a-list-from-config-ini-file)

But I am wondering how I can read in a list with multiple lists

For example, I have a **config.ini**:

```
[INPUT]
values = [[40000, 60000], [70000, 80000]]
```

A function in my **main.py** needs to read the above as:

```
[[40000, 60000], [70000, 80000]]
```

I am not sure if it matters, but values can be any size list, so for example:

```
[[40000, 60000]]
```

or

```
[[40000, 60000], [70000, 80000], [90000, 95000]]
```

I know the below will not work, but for clarity, I am reading the lists within the list into **main.py** like this:

```
self.values = config['INPUT']['values']
```

`self` is there because I am using a class. These are my declarations in the beginning of **main.py**:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read('config.ini')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a list (or list of lists or dict or whatever) as a string, and use `ast` to recover it.

Config:

```
[INPUT]
values = [[40000, 60000], [70000, 80000]]
```

And script (simplified as reading string variable from config is not a problem):

```
import ast
list_in_list = ast.literal_eval(string_var_read_from_config)
```

Comment: I formatted my config file to read in `values` as a string like the one you mentioned in your answer, would I now read it into my main.py as follows? `self.values = ast.literal_eval(['INPUT']['values'])`, if I run this I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I need the numbers within the lists to be read as integers.

Comment: No, you forgot that your values are stored in `config` object so `self.values = ast.literal_eval(config['INPUT']['values'])`

Comment: Thank you, your solution using `import ast` worked. But I noticed that the way it worked for me was by not making `values` in my config file a string. `values = '[[40000, 60000], [70000, 80000]]'` did not work for me because the numbers inside the list were still being imported as strings, however, putting `values = [[40000, 60000], [70000, 80000]]` in my config file did work. Not sure why this was the case, but maybe you might be able to elaborate on it.

Comment: I corrected myself. Config parser reads this value as a string by default. If you add quotation marks then it reads string with quotation marks in it. The `ast` module should recognize it as string and it did. So... no quotation marks.